Return in Python Decorator
def decorator(func):
  def wrapper(lst):
    new_list=[]
    for i in lst:
      i**=2
      new_list.append(i)
    return func(new_list)
  return wrapper

@decorator
def print_list(lst):
  print(f"Hello this is my list: {lst}")
my_list=[1,2,3,4,5]
print_list(my_list)

I would like to know that return func(new_list) return value to where and return wrapper returning to where?

Decorating the function is basically defining the function then doing print_list = decorator(print_list) immediately afterwards.
